# How to install specific version of ionic via npm

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework

What command do I need to run to install specific version via npm?

If I run the code **npm install -g cordova** it installs the latest version.
Since I'm using multiple laptops and computers I need them to have same versions when I switch back and forth to them.

This is the version of IONIC I am using and preferred:
I'd like to avoid and **update** them all as I may encounter bugs if I use the latest version.

```
Ionic CLI is out of date:
Locally installed version: 1.3.20
* Latest version: 1.4.3
* https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
* Run npm install -g ionic to update
```

btw, I found these releases via github https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/releases

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: `npm install -g ionic@latest` for the latest updated version

Answer (score 87, accepted):

## Syntax

To **install a specific version** through [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/), the following *syntax* should be followed:

```
npm install -g ionic@VERSION
```

- Where `VERSION` is the **number of the version** we want to **install** from **`Ionic`**

### Example

Let's say that we want to install **`IONIC 1.4.0`**, because you should specify:

```
npm install -g ionic@1.4.0
```

> #### Notes
>
> To see all available versions use: `npm info ionic`.

Comment: @Aki , how to change it to a specific version?

Comment: @user1872384 you check from the list npm created and then install that particular version

Answer (score 6):

**Linux:**

```
sudo npm install -g  ionic@2.2.0
```

**Mac**

```
npm install -g  ionic@2.2.0
```

Replace 2.2.0 for the version you want

Answer (score 2):

For example you want install 3.2.0 of ionic version then you need to install it by using below command.

npm install ionic@3.2.0 --save

If you want to install the latest version of ionic ,but already if you have the old one then use

npm install ionic@latest --save

Answer (score 1):

In addition you can update your package.json file

e.g.

```
"dependencies": {
    "ionic": "^1.4.3"
}
```

Where `1.4.3` is ionic version.

Comment: There is no dependency named ionic in package.json so can you please explain how to update the file ? as adding ionic : ^1.4.3 does not effect