# Revert to an older version of Ionic 2 CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

So I updated my ionic 2 cli and I hate it... There's soo many bugs. How do I revert back to an older version of Ionic 2? The one I want would be the one that includes Angular Rc 4.

The one I would like to revert back to is 2.0.0-beta.36

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316994/how-to-install-specific-version-of-ionic-via-npm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, altough this could be a duplicate and I marked it as one, still want to help you out a bit.

`npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.36`

or (not sure about the .)

`npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta36`