# Installing Ionic1 using ionic start.. on an up-to-date NodeJS

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

It appears after using "ionic start myfirstapp" that Ionic 2 is now the default version.

How can I install version 1 of Ionic? I have tried "ionic start myfirstapp --v1"
but after typing "ionic -v" it still returns 2.1.0

Comment: how do you check that it install version 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316994/how-to-install-specific-version-of-ionic-via-npm), you can install viw npm an older version of ionic like this

```
npm install -g ionic@1.4.0
```

Where you are installing ionic 1.4.0

Hope it helps.