# Install Ionic Cordova Error

Tags: macos, cordova, ionic2

I am trying to [install Ionic 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/installation/) on a OSx machine. I did install `Node.js`. When I run the following:

```
$ npm install -g ionic cordova
```

I get this error:

[image]

If anyone can assist, I would appreciate it.

**UPDATE:**

Downgraded Node to v6.9.1 and still get the same error:

[image]

**UPDATE**

As suggested below, I tried:

```
npm cache clean
```

But still get the same error:

[image]

**UPDATE**

If I try install a specific version, I get the following error:

```
sudo npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.20 cordova
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to install ionic in mac

you have to install nodejs .

to install ionic as per the official [doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/installation/) if you are using linux or mac you should use `sudo` command

try

```
sudo npm install -g ionic cordova
```

**note**

your npm version should be greater then 3.x

Comment: Thank you, that is the answer. Having sudo in front of the command.

Comment: I am trying to award you the 50 points bounty, but I have to wait 21 hours it says.

Comment: If I run the following `sudo npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.20 cordova` I get the error (see above). Do you know how I can fix that?

Comment: @Richard http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316994/how-to-install-specific-version-of-ionic-via-npm check this. and it is good to install the latest version of ionic

Comment: The reason I don't want to install the latest version, is because I have an existing app built in Windows, that I want to get working on iOS. It was built on ionic@2.0.0-beta.20.

Comment: ok then do `ionic -v` if that is not your version then go for `sudo npm uninstall -g ionic` and then do `sudo npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.20` after that give `ionic -v` and check the version of ionic

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting the same error above, no matter how I try install ionic now it seems. Is there a way to do a complete uninstall and start again?

Comment: I do try that (`sudo npm uninstall -g ionic`) also `npm cache clean`. But I still get the errors above when I try install with: `sudo npm install -g ionic@2.0.0-beta.20`. I there some way I can do a "clean"?. Should I uninstall `node` and `npm`?

Answer (score 0):

that version of node its the current so maybe its nos stable at all. I recommend to instal NVM (node version manager) from [here](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) this is like a "sand-box" where you have all node version you want and can switch between them.

You only need to run `nvm install 5.11.0` and nvm will download that node version for you. Then to use a specific node version you need to run `nvm use 5.11.0` and thats all.

I recommend to install 5.11.0 for example, its the node version that im using atm and its working fine with ionic2 RC3.

Comment: Thanks, I will give it a try.

Comment: The following says that Ionic2 only works with Node version 6 an up. Should I rather install version 6?  https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/setup/installation/

Comment: try if you want the 6.9.1 version

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the same error with v6.9.1, See above.

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading your node.js clean npm cache.

```
npm cache clean
```

and try the installation again

Comment: @artemho thank you for the suggestion, however I try do a clean, but still get the same error (see above).