# -bash: ionic: command not found (Not able to install any version)

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic4

I am trying to install ionic globally.

```
sudo npm install -g cordova ionic AND npm install ionic@3.2.0 --save
```

I tried both the commend it execute successfully.

But when i run ionic info it shows  **-bash: ionic: command not found**

Can anyone help me?

EDIT : Same thing happen when i install cordova

```
    sudo npm install -g cordova
Password:
/Users/hardik/.npm-packages/bin/cordova -> /Users/hardik/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
+ cordova@8.1.2
updated 1 package in 7.011s
Sshah-Mac-mini:node_modules sunny$ cordova -v
-bash: cordova: command not found
```

**Terminal Log**

```
  Sshah-Mac-mini:~ sunny$ npm list -g --depth=0
/Users/hardik/.npm-packages/lib
├── @angular/cli@7.3.5
├── cordova@8.1.2
├── ionic@4.11.0
└── npm@6.9.0

    Sshah-Mac-mini:~ sunny$ npm root -g
    /Users/hardik/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules


       ╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
       │                                                               │
       │       New minor version of npm available! 6.7.0 → 6.9.0       │
       │   Changelog: https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v6.9.0   │
       │               Run npm install -g npm to update!               │
       │                                                               │
       ╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

        Sshah-Mac-mini:~ sunny$ npm install -g npm
        /Users/hardik/.npm-packages/bin/npm -> /Users/hardik/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
        /Users/hardik/.npm-packages/bin/npx -> /Users/hardik/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npx-cli.js
        + npm@6.9.0
        updated 1 package in 16.501s
        Sshah-Mac-mini:~ sunny$ ionic info
        -bash: ionic: command not found
        Sshah-Mac-mini:~ sunny$
```

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo cordova -v`?

Comment: @Tachyon same reasult

Comment: What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: To get the version of cordova, you should use: `cordova --version` in console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install specific version of ionic via npm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316994/how-to-install-specific-version-of-ionic-via-npm)

Comment: @Tachyon echo path : /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it

By editing  ~/.bashrc with the following

export PATH=$PATH:/Users/EDIT_THIS_PUT_YOUR_USER_NAME_HERE/.npm-packages/bin

sudo npm install -g grpc --allow-root --unsafe

node-sass : npm rebuild node-sass

Answer (score 6):

This command show globally available modules in npm

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

if you cant see ionic cordova in this list it means both packages are not installed globally.

check your global installation path by

```
npm root -g
```

check if your ionic and cordova installed in this directory or not.
if you have tried path changing in first answer and still not working then uninstall node and install latest recommended version of node.

then install

```
npm install -g ionic
npm install -g cordova
```

Comment: after this have  you restarted machine?

Comment: then may be the last option is to  unistall complete node js then start again

Answer (score 2):

The first thing after the installation try this,

> sudo ln -s /home/USER/npm/bin/ionic /usr/bin/ionic

If still getting the error, you are using **Old version** of Ionic **Uninstall** it and Reinstall it again.

```
> npm uninstall -g cordova

> npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Then just reinstall

```
> npm install -g cordova
> npm install -g ionic
```

if still, it gives errors another solution is
Go to **user/.ionic** folder and **remove** all files then install ionic again by using the following commands.

```
> npm install -g ionic
```

Comment: No none of this working. I had updated question do you have any clue?

Comment: sudo ln -s /home/USER/npm/bin/ionic /usr/bin/ionic

Did you tried this?
Replace User with the user you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have my `nodejs` managed via `asdf`. After running `asdf reshim` the `ionic` executable was in my path correctly.

Answer (score 0):

None of answers fixed my problem.

On Mac OS Mojave

After `npm install -g ionic`

First I went to
Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨Users ▸ {your user}⁩ ▸ ⁨npm⁩ ▸ ⁨lib⁩ ▸ ⁨node_modules⁩

And copy `ionic` folder

Then I went to
‎⁨Macintosh HD⁩ ▸ ⁨usr⁩ ▸ ⁨local⁩ ▸ ⁨lib⁩ ▸ ⁨node_modules⁩

And paste `ionic` folder to here.

After that I type `ionic -v` to terminal and it works !

Answer (score 0):

use this command  in mac -> **sudo npm install -g ionic**

Answer (score 0):

For Mac OS Catalina (version 10.15), first install `nvm`. Follow the instructions here https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update and here https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/tips

...or just prefix your command with `npx` eg: `npx ionic --v`

Comment: For posterity, please show the code or a summary of it (perhaps those links aren't valid some time ahead)

Answer (score 0):

so i found a way to solve it and you can run this command after installing it:

```
alias ionic="`npm config get prefix`/bin/ionic”
```

and then you can run the process that you want.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/4201#issuecomment-549969836)